# UITableview prints only first object of NSMutableArray , IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray and a grouped tableview that I populate from NSMutableArray.

When I print NSmutableArray with NSLog Output is 
`"String1","String2","String3"`

But on UITableView Cell I always see the first item of NSMUtableArray:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return [_presenterList count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"_presenterList objectAtIndex: %@",[_presenterList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    cell.textLabel.text=[_presenterList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

output NSlog  `"String1"`

Output on tableview

```
String1
String1
String1
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT SCREEN SHOT ADDED

I create some headers from Strings and 1 tableview row like in the picture

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell.textLabel.text=[_presenterList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

instead of
 `cell.textLabel.text=[_presenterList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Answer (score 1):

You are returning "1" in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `[array count]` in `numberOfSectionsInTableView`. This is backwards (unless you really want a section for every item in the array.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_presenterList count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: If you are going to post this update to `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` you should also post the required update to `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle  I need exactly one row and section count that is equal to NSMutableArray Count plse see the screen shot on edited question , So your answer gives me 1 section and rows equal to NSmutablecount that is exact opposite of what I need

Comment: @MordFustang If this is the design you really want to go with take a look at the answer below.